# dracut.conf version of --uefi?

Tags: dracut

Looking through `man dracut.conf` I see equivalents to a lot of the command line options from `man dracut`, but I don't see one that causes it to generate a UEFI executable like `--uefi` would on the command line. There are other UEFI options in there, but nothing to cause it to make a UEFI executable. Am I overlooking something?